# Odd behavior in code repo and link to my open source git repo

Tags: codenameone

Now that things are sort of getting stable, I am still doing the codename one todo app demo and got to the point where I added underlines under the label/checkbox.  My git repo is

https://github.com/deanhiller/codenameOneExamples

****EDIT

I just published my build and ran on android phone and the basic todo app is not working either.  I am not sure what's wrong, and if I can't fix this it may be time to jump ship and create two apps(one swift and one android studio...bleck ).  I really like this concept and at 70/month, codeone was not a bad deal for what we need.

****END EDIT

If I click + 3 times though, the screen looks like this (settled on using intellij 2019.1.4 with codename 6.5.1 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4).  This is not what the demo should look like though.

[image]

**and thanks at the amazing support Shai**.

Comment: What is your question? Why, instead of posting a link to your repository, don't you show a specific example of minimal code (as short as possible) that exactly reproduces your problem and tell us exactly what the problem is?

Comment: The one quote "This is not what the demo should look like though" in the post describes what is wrong.  the screen shot (compared to the todo app tutorial has First Item, Second Item, etc).  The git repo is so one can quickly run it and see but I am afraid perhaps it's my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only defined the styles for the unselected theme. This means that when an entry is selected or pressed it's unstyled. You can see this by opening the theme in my repo and comparing it to your theme.

Since I wrote that book we've slowly moved to styling with CSS which isn't very different from the content of the book (slightly different syntax). That makes things like that easier since CSS implicitly defines all the 4 styles in the same way and changes things for a specific style explicitly. This is a bit more convenient. It's also easier to treat styling as code even though I'm not a fan of CSS.

The nice thing if you can "live edit" CSS which means changes instantly show in the simulator without interaction.

Comment: Awesome!!  @Shai Almog , is there a way to generate the css file from the theme designer?  In some cases, I am not sure how to do the css and that would answer my question very easily if I could tweak the theme and generate css then tweak the css.  For example, how to do background type, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Both the designer and CSS are very different so the conversion is too far from a 1 to 1 conversion.